# One million doubles

Tags: java, sorting

this is the problem

Write code to create an array of 1,000,000 doubles. Fill the array with random values between 10 and 5000. After filling the array sort the array in DESCENDING order. There are no restrictions on how you sort the array.

this is what i have so far

```
import java.util.Random;

public class OneMillionDoubles {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x = 10;
        double [] array = new double[x];

        int[] num = new int[10];
        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            num[i] = generator.nextInt(4999) + 10;

            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Why are you using `new double[x];` when you need a million?

Comment: whats the purpose of storing in a double when you generate ints?

Comment: "*this is what i have so far*". What then? I don't see any question here.

Comment: Ah, it must be homework time :).

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class OneMillionDoubles {
    static final int NUM_DUBS = 1000000;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double [] array = new double[NUM_DUBS];
        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DUBS; i++) {
            array[i] = generator.nextDouble();
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);
        //reverse the order of the array, O(n) operation....
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` will sort in ascending order, past that this answer looks correct and concise.

Comment: hopefully he can figure out the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there are no restrictions, ust use the `Arrays.sort` and `Collections.reverseOrder()`

```
Arrays.sort(yourArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Make sure your array is array of `Double[]` and not `double[]`. Cannot sort primitive types.

Comment: They need to be in descending order, so you'll need the overload of sort() that takes a custom comparator or you'll need to reverse the list after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = new int[1000000];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(4999) + 10;
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
// in reverse order
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
System.out.println();
```

I am not sure it compiles but the logic is right.

Comment: This generates random `int`s, not `double`s.

Comment: Don't print 1,000,000 elements. : (